# file owner doesn't belong to file group

Tags: linux, file-permissions

hopefully quick question regarding web server write and read permissions.

Here's the thing.
Currently I have this setup on a production server:

```
...
drwxr-xr-x  12 apache developers  4096 Apr 27 19:27 wp-includes
-rw-r--r--   1 apache developers  2380 Mar  3 17:37 wp-links-opml.php
...
```

Its a wordpress instalation and in the tiny example I have shown how files and folders are setup.

My question is: Since I belong to the developers group, shouldn't I be able to write to the instalation?
Yes I know that in the example, both files and dirs are don't have `g+w` set.

Also, what are the side effects of apache owning `wp-links-opml.php` and not belonging in to the `developers` group?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in the `developers` group you'll be able to read those things, but not write to them.  As you noted, group members do not have write permissions on either of those.

There's no downside to having an owner not belong to the group that owns a file, they'll just use the owner permissions.  Of course, you may, in this case, want to make it so group can write to those and owner cannot.  I'm always leery of things that apache is allowed to write to, especially if they're executable/code.